# Application design using DDD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I am designing solution strucure for an application.  I am planning to use Domain driven design. Asp.net MVC and Entity framework. Need your inputs in some areas.

Data Access is designed using Entity framework code first 
Reposirotires are built on top of EF Data Acces
Domain model is designed usind domain model on top of Repositories
Application serveices are built on top of Damain layer
UI is developed on top of Application services

The flow is

UI (controller) --> Application service --> Domain Layer --> Repositories --> Data Access --> Data base.

I am not very clear of how to share the data in between the layers.

My Domain model can be used to sahre data between Repositories, Data Access and Domain Layer. I am just thinking the way the data should be passed from Daomin Layert to Application Service and Application Service to UI. I can use DTOs, But not sure weather it is a good option or not, as i have some models are already in Domain Model, View model in UI.

Answer (score 0):

Reuse Domain Model or UI Model is not good, it will make your layers are tightly coupled. It's very difficult to develop large scale applications that way.

What you think is correct, Application is a thin layer, it's just a bunch of Actions which will be called directly from UI layer and information will be passed through an object called ActionParameter. ActionParameters are defined in Application layer and ActionParameter objects are constructed on UI layer and passed to Application layer.

Application will retrieve data from DB via Data Access Layer. An Query Action sometimes need to fetch data from many source, different domain entities and data need to be projected, transformed or formatted before return to UI layer. We will have something like ActionResult objects that contains all data to be returned to UI layer.

It seems there will be a lot of codes but I think it's necessary. Each layer has its own purpose and when we change one, other layers won't be impacted.

Comment: Your suggetion is to use DTO?

Comment: Yes, It seems so...he is saying to use DTO. And I also recommend the same in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Given the flow you describe, create view models in the UI layer to be instantiated by the controller. A view model is simple object to which the view binds. This should be decoupled from the underlying domain model to address concerns noted by **namkha87**.

As far as the data access layer, you can use the domain objects themselves for object-relational mapping since EF allows this. There is no need for an intermediate DTO here.

Another thing to consider is separating the model used for queries from one's used to invoke behavior. This way, you can ensure that an application service never exposes behavioral domain objects, only [read-models](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/). The problem with having an application service expose domain objects to outer layers is that it will allow those outer layers to invoke behaviors on those objects the results being undefined. When you only return read-only objects with no behaviors, this isn't a problem. For data coming back, don't have the UI layer created domain objects directly - [you should distinguish between entities and simple data](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/08/06/distinguishing-between-entities-and-data-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/).

Comment: My question, How can I pass data from Application services to UI ?

Comment: Create read-models for queries, which will in turn be bound to ViewModels in the UI layer. For commands, have UI layer call application service, passing required data, but not using domain objects to carry data. Overall, with this approach, no domain objects are exposed outside of the app service.

Comment: I called writes commands. So for writes, pass DTOs to application service from UI, don't have UI instantiate domain objects directly.